# Python Modularity for a number

Tags: python

How to create a itterative number 10digit long by taking a base number

Comment: first, provide your code what you tried

Comment: When does it stop? In your example, does it stop because `(7 + 3) % 10` would be `0`? Or are you aiming for an ID of a set length?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simple approach for Solution:

```
a=input()
while len(a)<10:
    b=int(a[len(a)-1])+int(a[len(a)-2])
    a=a+str(b%10)
print (a)
```

May This one helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
n= 16

while(len(str(n)) < 10):
    print(n)
    a = n %10 + (int(n/10))%10 # sum of last two digits
    n *= 10
    n += a%10   #adding the last

print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I'm assuming you want to stop once you reach a `0`.

Certain numbers, like `18` wouldn't reach a `0` ever, so also want to add a meximum length that the ID can be.

The following code runs the math until you reach a `0`, or until it reaches `40` digits.

```
def getID(number)
    maxlength = 40 - len(str(number))
    while maxlength:
        string = str(number)
        answer = (int(string[-2]) + int(string[-1])) % 10
        if answer == 0:
            break
        number = number * 10 + answer
        maxlength -= 1
    return number


getID(14) == 1459437
getID(15) == 15617853819
getID(16) == 1673
getID(18) == 17853819
getID(18) == 189763921347189763921347189763921347189763
```

18 is a number that repeats forever, so instead the loop ends once it reaches a set length.